# Django: TypeError: must be string, not datetime.date

Tags: python, django, session

I found an exercise online and I'm trying to solve it.
It's my first time with Django.

I have a page with a form. The user is presented with a field (name, birthday, email, etc.), and then the values are stored in the user's session.

The app appears to work correctly the first time the user submits the form.  The applicant details appear correctly, and checking the database shows that the data were stored correctly in the session.

However, on all subsequent page views, the application crashes with a weird error, and the only way to recover from the error is to delete the browser's session cookie or clear out the contents of the session in the database.

```
    ERROR: test_create_applicant (api.test_views.ApplicantTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pablo/Desktop/exercise-misbehaving-application/api/test_views.py", line 30, in test_create_applicant
    applicant = self.client.session.get_applicant_vo()
  File "/Users/pablo/Desktop/exercise-misbehaving-application/api/sessions/backends/custom_db.py", line 42, in get_applicant_vo
    return ApplicantObject.hydrate(self.get('applicant') or {})
  File "/Users/pablo/Desktop/exercise-misbehaving-application/api/value_object/base.py", line 48, in hydrate
    return cls(cls.hydrate_values(dehydrated or {}))
  File "/Users/pablo/Desktop/exercise-misbehaving-application/api/value_object/base.py", line 60, in hydrate_values
    for name, field in cls.fields.iteritems()
  File "/Users/pablo/Desktop/exercise-misbehaving-application/api/value_object/base.py", line 60, in <dictcomp>
    for name, field in cls.fields.iteritems()
  File "/Users/pablo/Desktop/exercise-misbehaving-application/api/value_object/fields.py", line 300, in hydrate
    return None if value is None else datetime.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
TypeError: must be string, not datetime.date
```

Can anyone point me on the right direction?

```
class Date(Field):
    """
    A field that contains a date object.
    """
    def hydrate(self, value):
        return None if value is None else datetime.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%d').date()

    def dehydrate(self, value):
        """
        :type value: datetime.date
        """
        return None if value is None else value.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    def make_public_value(self, value):
        """
        :type value: datetime.date
        """
        return None if value is None else value.isoformat()
```

Comment: convert the value to a string format before passing it to the strptime function. str(value)

Answer (score 1):

The traceback is pretty clear.

The `datetime.strptime` method takes a string, e.g.

```
datetime.strptime('2015-11-11', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

However, in your `hydrate` method, you have passed it a `datetime.date` object, so you get the error message:

```
TypeError: must be string, not datetime.date
```

Comment: Thanks Alasdair,

How should I continue?

Comment: You need to debug the code and work out what's gone wrong.  Maybe hydrate needs to be changed so it can handle dates as well as strings. Or maybe hydrate is being called with the wrong value, or maybe hydrate shouldn't be called at all. I can't tell, because I don't think you've shown enough code, and I'm not familiar with the library you are using (TastyPie?).